# TextToSpeech synthesizeToFile как узнать что файл создан?

Tags: java, android

Данный метод сохраняет синтезированный звук в файл `file`:

```
myTTS.synthesizeToFile(text, null, file, null);
```

Есть ли возможность сохранять данный звук в массив, минуя сохранение в файл?

Для данного метода есть слушатель:

```
myTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        System.out.println(".......START!!!  ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
        System.out.println("...........OK!!!  ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to synthesize sample text");
    }
});
```

Файлы сохраняются, но слушатель не работает.

Файлы синтезируются маленькие (20-40 КБ).

Что я делаю не так, и как узнать, что файл синтезировался и сохранился?

**Обновление**

Я делаю для себя говорилку русских и японских слов. В виду того, что при переключении языков получаются огромные "тормоза" особенно на русский язык, я решил сначала записать звуки, потом воспроизводить. Здесь два варианта - либо в массив и оттуда воспроизводить или записать файлы и их воспроизводить и потом удалять если не нужны. Собственно запись в массив синтезированных слов - хотелось попробовать, тем более слова занимают мало места. Но в данном случае больше интересует как заставить слушатель обозначить, что файл записан и можно синтезировать другой?

Comment: один "?" - вопрос
два "?" - большой вопрос
три "?" - истерика.

P.S. `System.out.println()` в Java никуда не пишет

Comment: @Barmaley почему никуда не пишет? В `out` ведь и пишет.

Comment: Само API такой возможности, похоже, не предоставляет. Может и не зря. А хранить что-то в памяти на андроиде не лучшая идея. И ведь файлы синтезируются маленькие это когда вы туда маленький текст передаете?

Comment: @Regent в Android'е `System.out` отсутствует. В старых версиях Android он был привязан к LogCat и генерил `Log.i()` причем только в эмуляторах. В новых версиях (уже давно) `System.out` уходит в `null`

Comment: @Barmaley просто напишите 2 строчки и сами посмотрите :-)

Comment: Похоже вы делаете велосипед, уже все реализовано в самом TTS. обратите внимание на метод `addSpeech`. Вам остается просто ассоциировать файлы и текст который будет воспроизводиться.

Comment: 1. System.out.println() - у меня работает и это оставьте его, дело не в нем.

Comment: 2. есть текст на русском и японском. Одно слово воспроизводим по японски другое по русски. При смене языка очень длительная пауза в воспризведении - минута или больше когда на русский язык переключаешь. И так после каждой пары слов. Текст ассоциировать несчем для addSpeech - нет файлов.  Звуковые файлы создаются путем synthesizeToFile. Вопрос как определить что файл создан?

Comment: 3. Только обратил внимание что название темы изменилось

Comment: Покажите ваш метод `myTTs.speak()` и HashMap.

Comment: `public void addTTS(String text) {
        if (isLoaded)
            myTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null,null);
        else
            Log.e("error", "TTS Not Loaded");
    }`
так воспроизводился текст, менялся только язык. Японский только в начале долго загружался, потом нормально при смене языка быстро отзывался, а вот русский каждый раз долго, поэтому я стал пробовать сначала записать звук.

Comment: Так записывал звук, но если запустить массив слов, то получаются файлы 0 кБ, неуспевает,  вот я и хочу узнать как узнать когда файл записан    `public void initSyn(String text, String nm) {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/","/Sound/" + nm + ".mp3");
        mTts.synthesizeToFile(text, null, file, null);
        mTts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
........
    }`

Comment: Сергей, попробуйте так                                                             `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "text");
tts.speak("text text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);`                             Тогда должен слушатель заработать. Надеюсь. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520018/utteranceprogresslistener-is-not-called-always-in-text-to-speech

Comment: Спасибо, я перед тем как сюда написать искал пример и этот тоже видел, но на данный код андроидстудио ругается, перечеркивает speek. Я посмотрел на http://developer.android.com/ - рекомендуют заменить на speak(CharSequence, int, Bundle, String). Вот я и сделал как сделал. Тоже самое и в отношении synthesizeToFile.

Comment: Стоит переместить код из комментариев в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем я обратил внимание на `myTTS.synthesizeToFile(text, null, file, null)` последний параметр `null`. Это - `String utteranceId`. Он может быть `null`, но в данном случае он необходим, поэтому в `myTTS.synthesizeToFile(text, null, file, "OKKKKKKEY")` последний параметр должен быть строкой, может быть даже пустой строкой - я попробовал работает

```
myTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
@Override
public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
    System.out.println(".......START!!!  ");
    ........
}
```

По поводу сохранения синтезированных звуков в массив - соглашусь с комментарием koks_rs.